# How to read each of the elements of a unix "ls" command?

Tags: linux, unix

I tried to google this, but I can't find a search term. Can someone go thru a bit what each of these are?

drwxrwxr-x   1 joe  496     16777216  9 Jun  2016 crunchbase.ns*

I know what rwx means but the others, not so much.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate; answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103118/63804)

Comment: Perfect, this is the search word: What do the fields in ls -al output mean?

Comment: Do you know what the 496 mean?  Is the group, but how do I check what it actually is?

Comment: The numeric group means something bad has happened and the group doesn't exist. Maybe the group was deleted without deleting its files first, or maybe you've mounted a filesystem from another computer with non-matching gids, or maybe the gid came from inside a tarball that was untarred as root.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice description of the long format for ls.

https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/ls-file-permissions.html

ls -la
    do a listing with long format and all files.
    the -l (long format) gives information about the file such as size and date.
    -a says to list all files, including hidden.  Hidden files start with a ".".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This looks pretty much like a link only answer. To reduce the risk it gets deleted via moderation, I suggest you try to improve your answer by putting content of that link directly in the answer.